# Merging two files based on 1st matching columns using awk command

Tags: unix, awk

We have two files Test1.txt and Test2.txt. We have to match 1st column of Test1.txt file with 2nd column of Test2.txt and then merge 2nd file with the 1st file. In the output we should select column 1, 2 and 3 from the 1st file and column 2 and 3 from the 2nd file. If there is no match with the 1st file then blank should be appended in output.

Tried with below command

```
awk 'NR==FNR{C[$2]=$1;A[$2]=$2; B[$2]=$3;next}$1 in C{$4=A[$1]; $5=B[$1]}1' FS=, OFS=, Text2.txt Text1.txt 

Text1.txt

PriId,testId,status,timestamp
007,1,ABC,20198743874398
006,2,PQR,43546346456565

Text2.txt

PriId,ReqId,ReqStatus,timestamp
007,100,XYZ,201934353532

Expected Output:-

PriId,testId,status,ReqId,ReqStatus
007,1,ABC,100,XYZ
006,2,PQR,,
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do wrap your samples in code tags.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Could you please check now

Comment: Try the `join` command, type `man join`.

Comment: Tried with Join command, as both files are not equal number of records this will mismatch records while appending. also data is huge need use     awk commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following(tested with provided samples only).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
FNR>1 && FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2 OFS $3
  next
}
FNR>1{
  print $1,$2,$3,a[$1]?a[$1]:","
}
'  Test2.txt Test1.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '
BEGIN{                              ##Starting BEGIN section from here, which will be executed before reading Input_file(s).
  FS=OFS=","                        ##Setting FS and OFS value as comma here.
}                                   ##Closing BEGIN section here.
FNR>1 && FNR==NR{                   ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when 1st Input_file is being read and FNR>1 will skip its 1st line.
  a[$1]=$2 OFS $3                   ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1 and value is $2 OGS $3.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
FNR>1{                              ##Checking condition FNR>1 which will run for all lines except 1st line of 2nd Input_file.
  print $1,$2,$3,a[$1]?a[$1]:","    ##Printing $1 $2 $3 and value of array a value whose index is $1 if its value is NULL then print comma there.
}
'  Test2.txt Test1.txt              ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: @Anant, please check explanation now.